# My kubernetes pods dont reach to a VM in the same network

Tags: linux, kubernetes, networking, centos, cri-o

I had to setup an cluster on CentOS virtual machines, and I did as I found on internet; at first seems like is working well, but recently i'm getting too much trouble with istio and communications. Well, my major problem is that I cant reach to a VM who has the database, the master node and the worker nodes can reach and telnet to the database VM, but the pods cant. Do I have to set some kubernetes network config?
Thanks (:

Comment: I used this tutorial
https://graspingtech.com/install-kubernetes-rhel-8/

Comment: Make sure that the Coredns is using host's /etc/resolv.conf https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.